# Full Calendar 3.5.0 in JSFiddle Doesn't Work

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar

As Full Calendar 3.5.0 recently came out, I wanted to try it on JSFiddle.
I linked all the necessary external links from CDNJS.

However, the

```
<div id='calendar'>
```

in the HTML of which in my JSFiddle does not work.

I am a beginner. I thought that CALENDAR ID was in the JS.

Has anyone tried the full calendar 3.5.0?

The calendar is not shown!

This is the link to the JSFiddle: [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/dbj0729/bgs1z1oe/2/)

Thank you for your support in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running your fiddle, check the browser console for errors. It'll tell you jQuery is not defined when fullCalendar is trying to use it. This is because fullCalendar relies on jQuery, but you loaded the fullCalendar library before the jQuery library, so fullCalendar can't find jQuery when it loads, because it doesn't exist yet.

You added the JS files in the wrong order, and you forgot to include momentJS at all. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/usage/ tells you what to include and what order to put them in.

> jQuery and Moment must be loaded before FullCalendar's JavaScript.

To fix:

1) Add a reference to momentJS

2) Re-order the references as per the fullCalendar docs. In JSFiddle you simply
 click the External Resources zone and then drag them into the correct order.

3) You included fullCalendar twice. You only need to include the `fullCalendar.min.js`. The only reason to use the full-fat `fullCalendar.js` is if you want to debug it, otherwise it just wastes bandwidth, and certainly should never include them both together (or include the same one twice), or else you risk conflicts.

Check the same thing with CSS as well - you also included fullCalendar.css and fullCalendar.min.css, which makes no sense for the same reasons as I outlined above with the JS files.

Comment: Thank you for your support! I will try to fix it the way you mentioned! Have a good day!